# C# and Linq to Entities using count in a where lambda statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following that returns all records that have a child.

```
var allStops = (from s in db.stop_details
                where db.billing_transactions.Any(c=>c.stop_details_id == s.id)
                orderby s.id
                select s).ToArray();
```

I want to know all records that have exactly 3 children, like:

```
var allStops = (from s in db.stop_details
                where db.billing_transactions.Any(c=>c.stop_details_id == s.id).Count() == 3
                orderby s.id
                select s).ToArray();
```

or

```
var allStops = (from s in db.stop_details
                where db.billing_transactions.Count(c=>c.stop_details_id == s.id) == 3
                orderby s.id
                select s).ToArray();
```

I just can't seem to get the syntax correct...

Comment: Do you have a database relationship between the two tables?

Comment: Yes I do, it traverses it correctly.

Comment: Why are you ignoring the answers? Is that just a newbie thing, or what?

Comment: No Johathan, I'm sorry...I had accepted the answer but my form apparently did not post.  I had it minimized until just now.  The answer is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you have a database relationship between the two tables, and assuming `billing_transactions.stop_details_id` is a foreign key, you should be able to do something like this.

```
var allStops = (from s in db.stop_details
                where s.billing_transactions.Count() == 3
                orderby s.id
                select s).ToArray();
```

Comment: As usual over thinking was the problem here...thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF you should use navigation properties instead. According to what I saw, you should have an one to many relationship between `stop_details` and `billing_transactions`, so `stop_details` entity should have a collection navigation property (lets call it `billing_transactions`). Your query could be like:

```
var allstops=db.stop_details.Where(s=>s.billing_transactions.Count()==3)
                            .OrderBy(s=>s.id)
                            .ToArray();
```

Now if you don't want to use the navigation property I suggest you to do a [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548539(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var allStops = (from s in db.stop_details
                join bt in db.billing_transactions on bt.stop_details_id equals s.id into bts
                where bts.Count()==3
                orderby s.id
                select s).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

using dot notation,  please  try the following example this assumes you have a  from billing_transaction to stop_details.

```
var allstops = db.stop_details
    .Where (s=>s.billing_transactionsc.stop_details_id.Count() == 3)
    .OrderBy (s => s.id)
    .ToArray();
```